# Looping error in Javascript with eventHandler

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code within and HTML page. Its function is to display elements on the form based on the user pressing a + button and if the element is not needed then it removes it via the user pressing the - button. Currently its throwing an error "TypeError: docs[n]" is undefined after the following sequence of events:

1. Select button to add elements
2. Remove elements not needed
3. **Add elements back (Error Thrown)**

Any help would be most appreciated

````
`<script language="JavaScript">`

       var idx = 0;



        var d;

            //Make getElementsByClassName work for all of IE revs
            if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
                document.getElementsByClassName = function (cn) { 
                var rx = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + cn+ "(?:$|\\s)");
                var allT = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), allCN = [],ac="", i = 0, a;
                while (a = allT[i=i+1]) {
                  ac=a.className;
                  if ( ac && ac.indexOf(cn) !==-1) {
                    if(ac===cn){ allCN[allCN.length] = a; continue;   }
                    rx.test(ac) ? (allCN[allCN.length] = a) : 0;
                  }
                }
            return allCN;
        }
    }
            function add_fields(e) {

            // for some reason, adding the new fields wipes out existing values, so save and restore
            var docs = document.getElementsByClassName("doc");
            var revs = document.getElementsByClassName("rev");

             ++idx;

            /*  console.log("test " + idx); */

            var saveDocs = new Array(idx); 
            var saveRevs = new Array(idx);

            for (n=0; n < idx; n++) {
            saveDocs[n] = docs[n].value;   **//Error is thrown here**
            saveRevs[n] = revs[n].value;
            }


            node = document.getElementById("content");
            theNewRow = document.createElement("tr");

                theNewCell = theNewRow.insertCell(0);
                theNewCell.innerHTML = "Approver Name";
                theNewCell.setAttribute("style","font-size: 12pt");

                theNewCell1 = theNewRow.insertCell(1);
                theNewCell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='doc' style='width:180px;' id='docNum0'/>";
                theNewCell1.setAttribute("style","padding-left: 10px");

                theNewCell2 = theNewRow.insertCell(2);
                theNewCell2.innerHTML = "Approver Email";
                theNewCell2.setAttribute("style","font-size: 12pt");
                theNewCell2.setAttribute("style","padding-left: 10px");

                theNewCell3 = theNewRow.insertCell(3);
                theNewCell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='rev' style='width:180px;' id='rev0'/>  <input class='minusThing' type='button' style='font-size:10px' value='- '/>";
                theNewCell3.setAttribute("style","padding-left: 0px"); 



                node.appendChild( theNewRow );



            // restore old arrays and add the id tags to the fields just added
            docs = document.getElementsByClassName("doc");
            revs = document.getElementsByClassName("rev");
            for (n=0; n < idx; n++) {
            docs[n].value = saveDocs[n];
            revs[n].value = saveRevs[n];
            } 


            docs[idx].id = "docNum" + idx;
            revs[idx].id = "rev" + idx; 
                }


            //for Loop the entries
            function myfunction() { 

                alert('Inside Function')

               var values = ""; 
               for (n=0; n <= idx; n++)
               {               
                var doc = document.getElementById("docNum"+n).value;
                var rev = document.getElementById("rev"+n).value;


                //alert(doc+rev);


                 //Call VbScript Sub and pass value
                    PassValues(doc,rev);
     ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've removed all the docs, `document.getElementsByClassName("doc");` is going to return an empty array. If you're incrementing `idx` before your loop, the loop will execute once and try to access `docs[0]`, which is undefined.

Comment: Did this help or are you still having problems?